# Preloading Images in NextJS

Tags: reactjs, next.js, preload

We are using NextJS 9.3.2 Framework with Static Site Generator i.e SSG with the introduction of Google Lighthouse 6 Largest Contentful paint (LCP)is affecting my Site performance score . Most of sites have a Hero Image in above the fold content.

SO i am looking to Preload the image to cut down the time of LCP. Can you guys guide how can i preload big Hero image in NextJS with SSG.

Comment: You may check out [next-optimized-images](https://github.com/cyrilwanner/next-optimized-images) and [lqip-loader](https://github.com/zouhir/lqip-loader). In case you want to have more control over the build process, I wrote this article [Create a Lazy-Loading Image Component with React Hooks](https://hangindev.com/blog/create-a-lazy-loading-image-component-with-react-hooks) which I briefly shared how you may create your own LQIPs(Low-Quality Image Placeholder) with the help of [sharp](https://github.com/lovell/sharp) in Next's `getStaticProps`  and pass to the page component via `props`.

Comment: Thanks for reply but our client didn't agree to Low-Quality Image image to placed as a placeholder until main image gets loaded we need to prerender the main hero image to cut down LCP

Comment: Prerender the main hero means to turn it into inline base64?

Comment: You mean to say that use sharp to generate webp image format during build time as Site is SSG and then inline image by using base64 image.  Please correct me if i am wrong.

Comment: I was just asking what you do mean by "prerendering the main hero image"?

Comment: Since images are very heavy in size i meant to Preload the image so that image is availabile even before browser requests for it.

Answer (score 8):

As [HawaiiFi suggests](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70356463/1067132), you can preload the image.

In Next.js you can achieve this by adding a `<link rel="preload" ...>` to next.js 's`<Head>` component.

```js
import Head from "next/head";

// Inside one of the components that loads on your page:
<Head>
  <link
    rel="preload"
    href="/path/to/image.ext"
    as="image"
  />
</Head>
```

Answer (score 5):

You should upgrade your [Next.js](https://nextjs.org/) and use [Image Component](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/image-optimization).
It will do the following great things -

1. Lazy load
2. new Webp format
3. Resize image on the fly based on the device sizes
4. Compress images
5. Set prirotiy true in props to preload above the fold images.

Implement it to see the magnificent rise in lighthouse score.

Though it has some limitations like static export and placeholder images is not currently available, it still is great to use.
For placeholder images, you can use some extra library like https://github.com/joe-bell/plaiceholder

Comment: The lack of SSG-support / `next export` makes it unusable in this scenario

Comment: Unfortunately there’s a poor cache policy that is unable to change yet: https://github.com/vercel/next.js/issues/19914, so for quite a while you might wanna stick to plain `<img >`

Comment: To clarify, only the *default loader* is not supported when using `next export`-  using a [cloud provider or a custom loader](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/image-optimization#loader) still works. The [image optimization caching](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/image-optimization#caching) has also been improved since then, and should no longer be a deterrent to not use `next/image`.

Comment: @juliomalves Do you use a custom loader that build\creates image sizes\webp on export time?   https://twitter.com/rauchg/status/1402613436081528836

Comment: `next/image` build-time optimization is not yet supported.

Comment: https://medium.com/ne-digital/how-to-improve-lcp-and-speed-index-for-next-js-websites-f129ae776835.

This article helped me in improvising the LCP score.

Answer (score 1):

In the component that includes the hero image that needs to be preloaded, use [next/head](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next/head) and simply pre-load that image.

I wouldn't use next/image. It's slower than other solutions to server image sizes dynamically.

That's another thing. You should [load images based on the browser size](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Multimedia_and_embedding/Responsive_images) using built-in HTML functionality.

Comment: How do you preload using head? I'm using next export. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `priority` attribute for that image so Next.js will automatically preload it.

```
 <Image
   src="/image.png"
   alt="hero"
   priority
 />
```

Explanation from the Next.js documentation:

```
priority={false} // {false} | {true}
```

When true, the image will be considered high priority and preload. Lazy loading is automatically disabled for images using `priority`.

You should use the priority property on any image detected as the [Largest Contentful Paint (LCP)](https://nextjs.org/learn/seo/web-performance/lcp) element. It may be appropriate to have multiple priority images, as different images may be the LCP element for different viewport sizes.

Should only be used when the image is visible above the fold. Defaults to `false`.

https://nextjs.org/docs/pages/api-reference/components/image#priority